# Importing hidden function from Python module

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-module

I'd like to import [`_init_centroids`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py#L626) function from [scikit-learn/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py). However, it's not listed in [scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/cluster/_*init*_.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/cluster/__init__.py#L17). Is there any "nice" way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Hidden" functions are a recommendation in Python, you can import them.

Try

```
from scikit-learn.sklearn.cluster.k_means_ import _init_centroids
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know that! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Python nothing is really private, so you import this function explicitly:

```
from sklearn.cluster.k_means_ import _init_centroids
```